# Androidify does not show correct graphic on my device

Tags: graphics

[Androidify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.androidify&hl=it) from Google that uses [svg-android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android) library, shows broken graphics when running on my low-cost Chinese tablet (Android 4.2.2). Look here:

[image: Androidify bad graphics]

Is someone else facing the same issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post a link to the nice app? I'd like to try it on my phone.

Comment: yes, sure! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.androidify&hl=it

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your issue. You need to disable hardware acceleration in Developer Options.

This step is for the Samsung Galaxy S4, but you should be able to find something similar for your tablet: `Settings > More > Developer Options > Force GPU rendering`.

Comment: I tryed with my low cost tablet. Without success, the problem arises with or without the "Force GPU Rendering" option activated. This is due to the poorly implemented graphic layer of the tablet, I suppose... Thanks anyway. Maybe a lot of people will solve the problem with your answer.

Comment: @Seraphim'shost After you change the value, can you restart tablet? See if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, no benefit

Comment: @Seraphim'shost Maybe you can change the other Drawing settings. If something works, let us know. You can post it as an Answer. :)